# Нахождение в двумерном массиве максимальное повторение чисел

Tags: java

В программе нужно объявить двумерный массив и найти строку либо столбец, в котором максимально часто повторяется какой либо элемент.

Пример:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Ответ: 3-я строка.

Как можно было бы описать этот алгоритм? Не могу придумать скелет для кода.

К примеру начал писать код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int SIZE = 3, a = 0;

    int[][] graph = new int[SIZE][SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            graph[i][j] = i+1;
            i = j+1;
        }
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(graph[i][j] +"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].length; j++) {
            if(graph[i][j] == graph[i+1][j+1]){
              a = a + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Довольно топорный вариант сделанный на коленке

```
        int resultIndex = -1;
        int maxCountInRow = 0;
        Map<Integer, Integer> iterationMap;
        for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
            iterationMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].length; j++) {
                int value = graph[i][j];
                if (iterationMap.containsKey(value)) {
                    iterationMap.put(value, iterationMap.get(value) + 1);
                } else {
                    iterationMap.put(value, 1);
                }
            }
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair : iterationMap.entrySet()) {
                if (pair.getValue() > maxCountInRow) {
                    maxCountInRow = pair.getValue();
                    resultIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(resultIndex);
```

В каждой строке мы считаем колчиство вхождений каждого уникального элемента, а в конце сравниваем с результатами прошлых итераций.

Comment: А можно попросить пошагово? Кое какие нюансы не ясные просто(

Comment: для Java 8 можно использовать `iterationMap.merge(graph[i][j], 1, Integer::sum)` вместо 6-и строк кода